# How to Resize and Reposition Chart Objects in Excel?

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I am writing a Matlab function to position the Chart in the Excel Sheet( Workbook ). I am using the following code to resize and position it.

```
Excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Width=400;
Excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Height=250;
Excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Left=50;
Excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Top=200;
```

As you notice, the postion, size are hardcoded. I would like to position the image where I can specify the cell address or the range to place the chart.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never worked in `matlab` but see if something like this helps you. BTW I am not sure about the `()` at the end of `.Top` and `.Left`

The below code should position the chart at B2

```
rRange = e.Activesheet.get('Range', 'B2');
Excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Left = rRange.Left();
Excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Top = rRange.Top();
```